# tcltest pass variable from -setup script to -body script

Tags: unit-testing, tcl

I am using `tcltest` to write some simple unit tests for my TCL procs.
I'm wondering if there is a way to make a variable from the -setup script visible inside the -body script? Maybe using upvar/uplevel somehow?
So far I have tried the naive approach which does produce an error ("Test file error: can't read "N": no such variable"):

```
tcltest::test equal4_test {
} -setup {
    set N 4
} -body {
    equal4 $N
} -result 1
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: the code runs fine here. This is the typical way to prepare a variable for a test. There must be some other problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in tcltest `-setup` and `-body` scripts are evaluated in the same context, which is the exactly same context as the context that calls `tcltest::test`. Any defined `-cleanup` script is also evaluated in that context. Internally, Tcl's `uplevel` command is used to enforce this, and *lots* of Tcl's own test suite depends on this so we're pretty sure that it works.

Something else is going on. Are you running this code in a namespace? If you are, you probably want to create the variable with:

```
variable N 4
```

instead of:

```
set N 4
```

to avoid a horrible misfeature of Tcl's (arcane-in-this-respect) variable resolution rules.

Comment: Hehm, you are right, I think, there is probably something wrong with the way I handle the packages and namespaces... I'll try to destille the essence of my mistake...